# Add index to mysql table with ndbcluster engine

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

I'm having trouble while adding index on mysql table with ndbcluster storage engine below is the error . [mysqlcluster ver. 7.4 GA]

```
mysql> alter table `sks_staff_office` add index `pid_index` (pid);
ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 156 'Unknown error code' from NDBCLUSTER

mysql> create ONLINE index pid_index on sks_staff_office(pid);
ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 156 'Unknown error code' from NDBCLUSTER

mysql> alter online table `sks_staff_office` add index `pid_index` (pid);
ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 156 'Unknown error code' from NDBCLUSTER
the link i reffered to is

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table-online-operations.html
```

update: Found that the table (with ndbcluster engine) cannot be altered when the table's database is in use by remote connections. here is process list dump

mysql> show processlist;

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------------------+---------------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+------------------+
| Id      | User         | Host                        | db            | Command | Time | State                             | Info             |
+---------+--------------+-----------------------------+---------------+---------+------+-----------------------------------+------------------+
|       1 | system user  |                             |               | Daemon  |    0 | Waiting for event from ndbcluster | NULL             |
| 3383487 | remote_user01| remote.example.com:51567    | staff_db      | Sleep   |    0 |                                   | NULL             |
| 3388329 | root         | localhost                   | staff_db      | Query   |    0 | init                              | show processlist |
| 3388422 | remote_user02| remote.example.com:41311    | staff_db      | Sleep   |  531 |                                   | NULL             |
| 3388511 | remote_user02| remote.example.com:41554    | staff_db      | Sleep   |  522 |                                   | NULL             |
| 3389659 | remote_user02| remote.example.com:45603    | staff_db      | Sleep   |  405 |                                   | NULL
```